# Angularjs Request/Response data is not coming from ESB

Tags: angularjs, wso2-esb

I am using webstorm IDE, and trying to get response from `wso2ESB` in angularJS using http.
But I'm unable to get response from ESB(Server). All I am getting is error callback method "**unexpected error**" is called. 
When I use `SoapUI` to check request/response it works fine.

```
var app= angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.getData = function () {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http' : 'myUrl'
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.data=data;

        },function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("unexpected error" + response.status);

        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are not setting value correctly when the promise is resolved,

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.data=data;
        }
```

Should be

```
.then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.data=response.data;
        }
```

Comment: i had tried number of values but it didn't, And it also display 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked
i already use these values
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE",
 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With,Accept",
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",